# First list item select by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html dropdown menu. I want to select only the parent ul list items by jquery.

**my menu code is:**

```
<ul>
 <li>list parent</li>
 <li>list parent  
  <ul>
   <li>list child</li>
   <li>list child</li>
   <li>list child</li>
   <li>list child</li>
   <li>list child</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>list parent</li>
 <li>list parent</li>
 <li>list parent</li>
</ul>
```

I want to select **only list parent** to stylize. **Not list child**

Comment: OK, so what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your root `ul` a class or `id` here:

```
<ul id="rootUL">
```

Then you can use:

```
$('ul#rootUL > li').css(...);
```

The `>` selector helps you to select `li` elements which are the direct children of your list with `id` named `rootUL`

Answer (score 0):

Add an identifier to the parent `ul` like an ID then use the child selector to select only its children

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>list parent</li>
    <li>list parent
        <ul>
            <li>list child</li>
            <li>list child</li>
            <li>list child</li>
            <li>list child</li>
            <li>list child</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>list parent</li>
    <li>list parent</li>
    <li>list parent</li>
</ul>
```

then

```
$('#nav > li')
```

Comment: if I select #nav > li and style them, the style also come on child li too.

Comment: because the css styles are inherited by the child `li` elements

Comment: so, what can I do without css. I don't want to use any css.

Comment: @user2946921 see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bSDUc/1/ - you can wrap the text inside another element and then style that element

Comment: have any way without wrapping?

Comment: @user2946921 are you using a class to style the elements or inline styling.. can you share the style rules you want to apply... edit the fiddle to recreate the demo

Answer (score 0):

The `>` selector allows you to select **only the direct children** of your elements.
So, assuming your root `ul` has a `.root` class set, you could use this :

```
$("ul.root > li")
```

Comment: if I select ul.root > li and style them, the style also come on child li too. but I want to select just parent and style them. Not child item

Comment: You're right, that's because `ul` inherits from your "list parent"'s `li`, so it gets its style. I guess I would wrap "list parent"'s texts around elements (like span or something semantically more suitable to your problem) and I would select those elements.


It doesn't feel incorrect since, you're not wanting to style **everything that's inside your "li"**, but only a small part of it (the text).